# Role-based DB design. Role as user attribute or role-specific tables

Tags: postgresql, database-design, user-roles

I'm developing a web application with several roles for its users. The DB in use is Postgres 10. The roles are very different and have much non-overlapping data so that oftentimes a specific table should belong only to one role and not to another.

In the examples below, I'll use two roles: *seller* and *buyer*. The first role is assigned to a user which has some company and sells goods. The second role is assigned to a user who buys goods and can receive gifts. *Seller* cannot receive gifts and *buyer* cannot have a company. Both *seller* and *buyer* can have an avatar.

I'm considering the following four designs with their cons and pros.

### Case 1

[image: case 1]

Here we have a *role* [reference table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_table) which enumerates all the roles in the system (*seller* or *buyer*), *user* table with password and email of the user which references the role table, *avatar*, *company* and *gifts_recieved* tables reference *user* table.

**PROs**

- No tables have NULL-able attributes

**CONs**

- Trigger should be used to check referential integrity. For example, if a *user* with *id=1* is a *buyer*, we should prevent insertion of a row to the *company* table with  *user_id=1*. Thus, we should create a trigger on **every** role-specific table which references *user* table to guard referential integrity.

### Case 2

[image]

Here, *user* table contains nullable role attributes: *seller_id* and *buyer_id* (or other roles which are not in the example). Only one of them is not NULL and it defines user's role. All role-specific tables reference either *seller* or *buyer* table. *Avatar* table which is common for both roles continues to reference the *user* table.

**PROs**

- No need for triggers to guard referential integrity of role-specific tables: they all reference either *seller* or *buyer* table.

**CONs**

- NULL-able role attributes.
- A single trigger (not triggers for all tables as in case 1) is required to ensure only one of role attributes (*seller_id* or *buyer_id*) is not NULL and all other are NULL.

### Case 3

[image]

To avoid NULL-able role attributes, we'll use Postgres' [inheritance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/tutorial-inheritance.html) for tables (this feature is not supported by MySQL). Here, *user* table is 'swallowed' into *seller* and *buyer* tables. *Avatar* table has got duplicated and prefixed with role name.

**PROs**

- No NULL-able role attributes.
- No triggers at all.

**CONs**

- Tables which are common for different roles are duplicated - a pure waste of resources.
- Inheritance is Postgres-specific feature.

### Case 4

[image]

To solve the duplication problem from Case 3, *avatar_id* was moved to *user* table from which *seller* and *buyer* inherit. Thus, for every table which is common to *seller* and *buyer* we'll add an attribute to their parent table (*user*).

**PROs**

- No triggers for referential integrity
- No table duplication
- No NULL-able atrrributes

**CONs**

- Postgres inheritance has its caveats: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-inherit.html

## Question

What solution of the above fit the best DB design practices (if any)? Should user role be an attribute of user table or be a specific table(s)?

### Clarifications

1. A seller can have only one company.
2. A user identified by email/password pair can be either a seller or a buyer.

Comment: It is not clear if there is just one company or several companies. Also it is not clear if a seller can be a customer as well and if there are more than one company, a seller in a company might be a customer to another company. In that case I would go for case 1 but without triggers and let the server side of the web application make the decisions that you would use triggers for in case 1. In any case I would avoid inheritance in case I need to change DB provider. Design practices are tricky though and I often had to invent my own in specific situations.

Comment: A seller has only one company and a user can be either a seller or buyer. I've added clarification to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

I am partial to Case 2.

I would not consider Cases 3 and 4 because of the use of inheritance.  I have not visited this topic in many years, but my biggest concern about it was whether developers using a database implementing inheritance would be able to wrap their minds around how to use it.

The trigger is the sticking point for Case 1 in my mind.

Are you aware that you do not need a trigger in Case 2?

```
create table exclusion_constraint (
  user_id int,
  seller_id int,
  buyer_id int,
  check (case
          when coalesce(seller_id, buyer_id) is null then false
          when seller_id is not null and buyer_id is not null then false
          else true
         end)
);
CREATE TABLE

insert into exclusion_constraint values (1, 100, 200);

ERROR:  new row for relation "exclusion_constraint" violates check constraint "exclusion_constraint_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, 100, 200).

insert into exclusion_constraint values (2, null, 200);
INSERT 0 1

insert into exclusion_constraint values (3, 100, null);
INSERT 0 1

insert into exclusion_constraint values (4, null, null);

ERROR:  new row for relation "exclusion_constraint" violates check constraint "exclusion_constraint_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, null, null).
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, really nice check constraint!